# In how many ways $n$ balls can be given to $k$ children so that no child gets more than $3$ balls when balls are distinct/identical?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

> In how many ways $n$ balls can be given to $k$ children so that no child gets more than $3$ balls when balls are
>
> a) balls are distinct
>
> b) balls are identical

I am trying to solve this problem using the inclusion-exclusion principle. I have seen a lot of similar questions to this, however, I cannot figure out the answer and get very confused when there are no numbers and it's only letters.

Here's my work so far:

**a) use the stars-bars method**

> I thought about using the same method in this [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1625677/how-many-ways-are-there-to-distribute-8-balls-into-6-boxes-with-the-first-two-bo), but I'm not sure how to divide the letters into cases.

**b) use the inclusion-exclusion principle**

> We want to satisfy the equation:
>
> $x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_k = n$, where $ 0 \leq x_i \leq 3$
>
> Then, we can start off by saying:
>
> $(n+k-1 \choose k-1)$ *(base case)*- $n-3+k-1 \choose k-1$ *(exclude cases with children more than 3 balls)* + **?**
>
> I am not sure if my work is correct, and I am not sure what to add to the **?** part. I know I'm supposed to add something because we over-substracted the amount of "wrong" (?) cases, but I don't really get that part.

Comment: Well, just considering the case of identical balls, if $F(n,k)$ denotes your function then, considering how many balls Child$_1$ gets, we have $F(n,k)=\sum_{i=0}^3 F(n-i, k-1)$ so you can compute it recursively.  At least that should provide lots of examples to study.

Comment: A generating function approach to the identical balls part is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2+x^3)^k = \left(\dfrac{1-x^4}{1-x}\right)^k$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us take case **(b)** (identical balls) first and solve a concrete example for $15$ balls, $4$ children, $0-5$ balls  per child.

Then using sticks-and-stones with inclusion-exclusion,
we get $\dbinom{15+4-1}{4-1} - \dbinom41\dbinom{12}3 + \dbinom42\dbinom63 = 56$

and if we want to generalise the formula for $n$ balls, $k$ children, $0-m$ balls/child,
$$\sum_{j=0}^J(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}\binom{n+k-1-j(m+1)}{k-1},\; J = {\left\lfloor\frac{n}{m+1}\right\rfloor}$$

Now to come to case **(a)** (distinct balls), for each allowable **pattern** (written systematically in descending order,say),eg $5-5-5-0,\; 5-5-4-1,\;5-5-3-2\;$ etc
you need to take the product of two multinomial coefficients for  $[Lay\; Down\; Pattern]\times[Permute\;Pattern]$

eg if we distributed the balls in the pattern $5-5-3-2$,

$$\binom{15}{5,5,3,2}\binom{4}{2,1,1}$$

which you can write more conveniently in the permutation version of the multinomial coefficient  as $$\frac{15!}{5!5!3!2!}\frac{4!}{2!1!1!}$$

And you would need to sum up the results for all allowable patterns

Comment: Note that in the distinct balls case, you need to sum over all the allowed patterns (here $5,5,5,0$ and $5,5,4,1$ and $5,5,3,2$ and $5,4,4,2$ and $5,4,3,3$ and $4,4,4,3$, though in other cases there could be many more)

Comment: Yes, explicitly included.